# Hide Background on moving Li to Top

Tags: jquery, html-lists, jsfiddle

I need one help
On clicking on Li  i am taking that at top its working fine you can see here

http://jsfiddle.net/65fed/1/

```
 var theLis = lis.get(); // to be sorted
        if (li.is(":animated")) return; // stop double clicks!
        arrayMove(theLis, li.index(), 0);
```

In my application i have white background
But whats happening while moving that li  the background comes white as my app  has white background.
What i need is that when my li moves at top   it should adjust the backgroung in this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/N2Py9/

```
  $('li.method-item').click(function () {

    var $this = $(this),

    callback = function () {
        $this.insertBefore($this.siblings(':eq(o)'));
    };
    $this.slideUp(500, callback).slideDown(500);
});
```

Note : But approach should be taken as the first link oi provided.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you might want to add some ore detail as to what you want. As it stands, it is hard to know what you want.

Comment: See what i wants is that.
Suppose i have 5 Li

Now suppose i am moving 4th Li to top whats happening that when 4th Li moves from its position all 3 lis above it moves down
and at that time white background shows.


I need is that when i click on 4th Li it moves to top first and then those remainig Li moves down together.

Comment: Means i just need that suppose when i click on 4th li, It should go to top at 0th position at the same time 5th Li should come at 4th position
 and when 4th Li reach at Top it shifts all Li below means autoAdjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one I put together

http://jsfiddle.net/65fed/3/

you might have to alter it to check if it is the first item that is clicked though.

```
$('li.method-item').click(function () {
    var item = $(this);
    var ul = item.parent();
    item.css({
        position: 'absolute', 
        top: item.position().top, 
        width: item.width()+'px',
        background: '#fff'
    });
    item.animate(
        {top: 0}, 
        {speed: 200, complete: function(){
            var itemclone = item.detach();
            itemclone.css({position: 'relative', top: '0px', background: 'none'});
            ul.prepend(itemclone);
        }}
    );
});
```

**EDIT :**
**Use the one in the fiddle below**
I have updated it to take make sure the clicked one is always on top and also to check if the first item is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/65fed/4/

Comment: Hi, Your code works fine and fullfill the functionality But when i am applying to my code its giving problem. 
The first problem is that my whole design spreads. On clicking on Li i am changing its css name to 'Selected' 
Clicked Li moves to top but background becomes white so i remove that background: '#fff', background: 'none', 
Ok thats fine but width is creating problem i.e width: item.width()+'px'

 Now all Lis are not of a same width some are moving back and some forward .
In Previous code i didn't specify width to any Li now applying creating problem of proper adjustement

Comment: How do you expect me to help you with this? I can not see your design.

Comment: Hi, I resolved that width issue ,thanks for nice work
but  speed is not constant
Means Clicking on second li it moves with slow speed
and when click on 4th li it moves with high speed.

I wants that all clickable Li should move with constant speed From any index

Comment: just multiply the items index value by a speed value and send the result as the speed value. Surely you don't need another fiddle for this.

Comment: Yes I tried that but speed not constant
You can Check it
http://jsfiddle.net/GqH44/1/

Comment: it's duration, not speed. you can also change the easing from the default 'swing' to 'linear' if you want constant speed. http://jsfiddle.net/GqH44/2/